# Can I prove $2^{-n}$ converges to $0$ without invoking the Axiom of Completeness or the Archimedean property of the reals?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to show that for any real number $x > 0$, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $2^{-n} < x$ without invoking the Axiom of Completeness or the Archimedean property of the reals?

Comment: Doing that proves the Archimedean property, so I'm not so sure what "invoke" should mean.

Comment: You need some property that distinguishes the rational numbers with the usual metric from the rational numbers with the $2$-adic metric; in the $2$-adic metric this sequence diverges.

Comment: Doesn't non-standard analysis work in a complete field that contains the real numbers in which this series does not converge to zero (and you guessed right, the field is not archimedian)?

Comment: @Dirk Sort of. The catch is that hyperreal analysis generally doesn't use the word "limit", instead obtaining the standard concept as "the standard part of the result of substituting an infinite number in some domain, provided this standard part doesn't depend on the infinite number we chose".

Comment: @Dirk: The hyperreals are (very badly) incomplete, when viewed from the external perspective. (they are, of course, complete when viewed internally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified what properties you *are* allowing to be used.

It's pretty easy to find ordered fields where such a sequence can't converge to zero. For example, take any ordering on the field of rational functions $\mathbb{R}(x)$ i.e. the field of all functions that can be written as the quotient of two polynomials. Without loss of generality, we can take $x$ to be a positive and infinite; that is, $x > a$ for all real numbers $a$.

In this field, we always have $0 < 1/x < 2^{-n}$ for every natural number $n$, so the sequence clearly cannot converge to zero.

There are even worse examples; in some ordered fields, the only convergent sequences are the ones that are eventually constant! (where "sequence" is limited only to sequences indexed by natural numbers)

(if you replace the field of rational functions with some other suitable example, then all of the above applies to *real closed fields* as well, which is basically just a completeness axiom suitable for working with polynomials)

Answer (score 1):

If for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N_{\varepsilon}\in\Bbb N$ such that $2^{-N_{\varepsilon}}<\varepsilon$, then for all $\alpha>0$ you have $2^{N_{1/\alpha}}>M$. Which proves the archimedean property. So I guess you cannot avoid it. Completeness can be avoided and, in fact, if you try to prove it as usual you won't ever need to use the fact that bounded sets have a least upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define convergence.

If you define $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to converge to $a$ if, for every positive *rational* $\varepsilon$, there exists $k$ such that, for $n>k$, $|x_n-a|<\varepsilon$, then you don't need the Archimedean property.

Indeed, it's easy to show that, for every natural $n$, $2^n>n$ and the argument can be quickly completed.

However, you need the Archimedean property for proving that, given a positive real $\varepsilon$ there exist a rational $q$ such that $0<q<\varepsilon$. This is necessary for the above definition to be equivalent to the one with “for every positive *real* $\varepsilon$”.

Answer (score 0):

The "Archimedean property" is already present in the natural numbers, and can be proven from the Peano axioms. It therefore makes no sense to avoid making use of it.

Let an $x\in{\mathbb R}_{>0}$ be given, and put $$n:=\left\lceil{1\over x}\right\rceil\geq{1\over x}\ .$$ The set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,2^n\}$ contains the $n+1$ numbers $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $\ldots$, $2^n$. It follows that $2^n>n$, hence
$$0<2^{-n}<{1\over n}\leq x\ .$$

Comment: "Is this invoking archimedean property?" I claim $\left\lceil \frac1x\right\rceil$ does not exist, since you've been so unlucky to choose $x$ to be the reciprocal of a very special real number which is bigger than any natural number.

Answer (score 0):

For $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real number such that $\epsilon > 0$ 
let $N_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ be the smallest integer such that
$N_{\epsilon} > ln(\frac{1}{\epsilon})/ln(2)$.
Then for all $n>N_{\epsilon}$, $2^{-n}<\epsilon$.

Comment: I think you need the Axiom of Completeness to ensure $\log_2\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$ is well defined.

Comment: Edited to the more palatable term.